# Solving Discrete logarithm Problem ($6^x=112\!\!\!\mod\!\!151$) from given equation

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, discrete-logarithms

I'm trying to solve the discrete logarithm problem $6^x\equiv112\!\!\!\mod\!\!151.$
I am given that 
$6^{72}\cdot112^{65}\equiv112^{136} \!\!\!\mod\!\!151$
I then calculate from this equation that
$6^{72}\equiv112^{71}\!\!\!\mod\!\!151\quad\mathbf{(1)}$

I use the extended euclidean algorithm to find out that
$\gcd(71,150)=1\;$ and $\;71\cdot131=1 \!\!\!\mod\!\!150\quad\mathbf{(2)}$
So now I raise both sides of $\,\mathbf{(1)}\,$ to the power of $\,131\,$ which gives us
$62^{72\cdot131}\equiv112^{71\cdot131}\!\!\!\mod\!\!150$
$\implies6^{72\cdot131}\equiv112^1\!\!\!\mod\!\!150\quad\mathbf{(2)}$
$\implies 6^{9432}\equiv112^1\!\!\!\mod\!\!150$
$\implies6^{132}\equiv112\!\!\!\mod\!\!150$
$\implies\log_6(112)\equiv132\!\!\!\mod\!\!150$

So from this, I conclude that $x = 132$.
I know this is a wrong answer since $\;6^{132}\equiv123\!\!\!\mod\!\!151$.
Can anyone help me show where I went wrong or another way of solving this without a computer?
If it helps the answer should be $\,x=47\,.$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is not true that $6^{72}\equiv 112^{71}\pmod {151}$.  Similarly, it is not true that $6^{72}\times 112^{65}\equiv 112^{136}\pmod {151}$.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry but I don't understand. 
My understanding is that I am given that $6^{72}≡112^{71} (mod 151)$
and I must solve for x in the equation $6^x≡112 (mod 151)$

Comment: I don't know what you were given, but that congruence is false.  $6^{72}\equiv 72\pmod {151}$ and $112^{71}\equiv 146 \pmod {151}$.  Your computation looks fine (given the false data your started with).

Comment: @lulu That's strange. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Ah, typos and algebraic errors happen all the time.  Not so strange.

Comment: @SebastianSigurdarson, in the last equalities you should write $\pmod{151}$ indeed only the exponents are $\pmod{150}$, not the powers.

Comment: Please delete the question and repost only when you have a *true* given congruence (else you may waste the time of many readers on an incorrectly posed problem).

Comment: @SebastianSigurdarson, you could write the following true congruence $6^{37}\equiv112^{71}\pmod{151}$ and solve the exercise by using it.